# How to expose API in Android kernel

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, android-source

How to expose an API in Android kernel? Somehow the following does not work:

1. I did `EXPORT_SYMBOL(module1_func)` in `module1.c`
2. Did `extern module1_func();` in header file `module1.h` (placed the header file in `'kernel/include/linux'`)
3. In `module2.c`, I did `#include <linux/module1.h>` and called the function `module1_func()`

FYI: `module1.c` is in `kernel/security/<clean>` AND `module2.c` is in `kernel/mm`

After compilation I am getting the following linker error:

```
kernel/mm/built-in.o: In function `get_param':
:(.text+0x75c0): undefined reference to `module1_func'
make: *** [.tmp_vmlinux1] Error 1
```

Btw, I did a clean build, still the same.

Comment: The link error is in a built-in.o object file.  Is module1_func() being referenced from a module or from the kernel binary?  You can't link to modules from the kernel because symbols will not be available.  Try building module1 as a loadable module.

Comment: @ Peter L. thanks for the reply. 

FYI: module2.c is kernel (rather actual file is 'page_alloc.c') and module1.c is driver. 
Could you pl tell me how to call a function in driver (module1.c) from module2.c (i.e. page_alloc.c) ?

Comment: To call a function from the kernel that is exported from a loadable module you can define a dispatch table, initialize each callback as null, then let the loadable module populate it.  The kernel code could then check for null and call it if it were not.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `extern module1_func()`, only declare `module1_func()` in `module1.h`.

Refer [this](https://github.com/jeyaramvrp/kernel-module-programming/tree/master/depmod-export-sym-demo) basic module for `EXPORT_SYMBOL()` understanding.

Comment: Thanks Jeyaram. I saw your example. Could you pl suggest how to call a function in "driver" (module1.c) from kernel code (like page_alloc.c - referred to as 'module2.c' in my question) ?